# How to recover implicit arguments of inductive types in a match expression?

Tags: lean4, pattern-matching, implicit-argument

```
def IsEven: Nat → Prop
| Nat.zero => True
| Nat.succ pred => ¬IsEven pred

inductive Example: Nat → Prop
| IsExample: IsEven n → Example (n + 10)
```

Here, `IsExample` has an implicit parameter `n`. Let's say I have a value of type `Example m`, and in order to use it in a proof, I need to refer to the `n`. How can I do that?

```
def sillyExampleFunction
  (e: Example m)
:
  IsEven m
:=
  match e with
  | Example.IsExample isEven =>
    -- How may I access the value of `n` here?
    sorry
```

---

For implicit function parameters, this is possible with function literals by putting the implicit parameters inside curly braces:

```
def IsMonotonic
  (fn: Nat → Nat)
:=
  -- `n0` and `n1` are implicit parameters.
  ∀ {n0 n1: Nat}, n0 ≤ n1 → fn n0 ≤ fn n1

def doubleIsMono:
  IsMonotonic (fun n => 2 * n)
:=
  fun {n0 n1} le =>
    -- Here we may use `n0` and `n1` in our proof.
    sorry
```

I've tried matching with

```
  | Example.IsExample {n} isEven => sorry
```

but I'm getting the error "too many arguments".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Lean `@foo` is like `foo` but with all arguments made explicit, see documentation on [implicit arguments](https://lean-lang.org/lean4/doc/implicit.html) (search for `@`). To pattern-match against implicit arguments, use the `@foo` variant, as in this simple example:

```
inductive Cow : Type
| moo : ∀ {k : Nat}, k = 42 → Cow

-- moo has an implicit argument k

def milk : Cow → Prop
| @Cow.moo k p => (p = p) ∧ (k = k)
```